# is Fork() different in Cygwin (on Windows) and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, fork, pid

I'm using this code in both Linux and in Cygwin (on Windows) and the output order is different and I have no clue why..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>



int main()
{
        pid_t pid;

        /* fork a child process */
        pid = fork();

        printf("\n PID1 %d\n",pid);

        pid = fork();

        printf("\n PID2 %d\n",pid);

        return 0;
}
```

the output in windows is:

```
 PID1 3888

 PID1 0


 PID2 5564
 PID2 7772

 PID2 0

 PID2 0
```

but in Linux (and MAC) it looks like

```
PID1 2486

 PID2 2487

 PID2 0

 PID1 0

 PID2 2488

 PID2 0
```

My question is PID2 ( PID2 2487) comes before PID1 in Linux but not in Windows (the output behavior is the same every time I run the code)

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `fork` via Cygwin?

Comment: Yes, `fork` is an atomic syscall on Linux. It does not exist (so is emulated in a complex way) on Windows.

Comment: thank you for your respond . yes, I do.

Answer (score 4):

After a fork(), it is indeterminate which process—the parent or the child—next has access to the CPU.On a multiprocessor system, they may both simultaneously get access to a CPU.An operating system can allow you to control this order. For instance, Linux has /proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first.

Comment: I'm really sorry if I sound naive , but is this applied for all parents and children in the same code (I had 2 forks in my code) so I'm imagining this like a grandpa and his children which are parents for the grandsons. Can a grandson apply before his parents (which is a child for the original code)

Comment: Note that even if your process gets first dibs on the CPU, that isn't an absolute guarantee that it will complete writing the output before the other process.  It might not if the current timeslice is very nearly over, for example, or if something else (like a hardware interrupt) slows you down.

Comment: @user3382285 it is always better to implement synchronization techniques if you are not 100% sure of the order of process being executed.

Answer (score 3):

The order in which the processes run in post-fork is unspecified.

Comment: thank you for your respond, as I know that the order between the child and the parent is unspecified. but in my case PID2 (for the second fork()) always comes before PID1 in Linux but not in window. my only thought is that the terminal output buffering in Linux and MAC has something to do with it.

Comment: By "always" you really mean "every time I've tried".  All that really means is that something is strongly biasing the results ... possibly some implementation detail subject to change, perhaps even just some irrelevant difference like the model of the two computers in question.  It still might happen the other way around sometimes, just not often enough for you to have seen it.

Comment: Even better: with some luck, on a multicore system the parent and the child may be scheduled perfectly at the same time.